# Pull to Refresh (ios)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I recently implemented pull to refresh here: https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh. It kind of works however it gets stuck with a spinning activity indicator. Their is also no text to the right of the arrow. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Not much code. Just added the classes and quartz core. Then subclassed my table view controller
Code:
@interface RootViewController : PullRefreshTableViewController
and added a void refresh

Comment: Try to do it with VoiceOver enabled and feel the pain VoiceOver-users feel when using apps with that terrible refreshing UI.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Without code there's not much anyone can say, but maybe try a different implementation of Pull To Refresh, like the [enormego (EGO)](http://developers.enormego.com/) version, the code is at [github, here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh)

It's used in the Facebook app so it definitely works.

Comment: how you know that it is used in facebook app.

Comment: @Developer see here: http://developers.enormego.com/view/facebook_redux_happy_ending

Answer (score 15):

Apple has introduced UIRefreshControl in iOS6. You can integrate it in your UITableViewController using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    // Configure Refresh Control
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Configure View Controller
    [self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
}
```

the refresh: method will trigger the update and you can stop it in your API callback using:

```
 [(UIRefreshControl *)sender endRefreshing];
```

Answer (score 13):

I am new to iOS development and I was trying to implement the pull to refresh in iOS 6.  Well looking for a solution, I stumbled across this blog post and found it to be very helpful, http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/iOS-6-Pull-to-Refresh-(UIRefreshControl).aspx.  It lays out the steps to implementing pull to refresh in a way that is easy to follow. Anyone looking to do this themselves in iOS 6 should check out the blog.

The UIRefreshControl is only useable with a Table View currently.  There are a few steps to follow to successfully add a refresh control:

1.
 Create a callback method to handle your refresh logic.  The callback method should be invoked when a user pulls down on the table view.  The signarture of the method should take one parameter: a pointer to the UIRefreshControl.

**Note: Steps 2-4 are all done within the Table View Controller’s viewDidLoad method.**

2.
 Instantiate the UIRefreshControl with a basic "alloc/init".

3.
 Connect an action to the refresh control to invoke your callback method when the ValueChange event is fired.

4.
 Add the refresh control to the Table View Controller's "refreshControl" property.

Comment: Could you add an excerpt of that page, so your answer will stay useful when the link dies? Also, we're more interested in the technical details (the actual answer), than in recommendations for blogs.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the EGO implementation than the leah one because it does not require a subclass of your view controller. The original EGO one in github is a bit of a mess with no .gitnore file and lots of .DS_Store files added unnecessarily. Take a look at some of the many forks and pick one.

The "emreberge" fork looks like a good version, better file organisation and documentation too!

https://github.com/emreberge/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Answer (score 2):

I found this library very useful, fancy and up-to-date: https://github.com/Yalantis/Pull-to-Refresh.Rentals-iOS

(Recommendations from other answers seem old and not maintained)

Answer (score 1):

Now, with newer versions of iOS than the above stated iOS 5 you can use: **UIRefreshControl.**

There is a really good tutorial on creating your own custom pull to refresh for your iOS Application: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-pull-to-refresh-in-your-ios-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can use : https://github.com/ngocbinh02/httablekit

Support iOS 5.0 or later

Pull to refresh tableview

```
    import <HTTableKit/TableKit>

....

//like UIRefreshControll

[tableview setPullToRefreshControlType:UITableViewRefreshControlTypeSystem]; 

[tableview  setPullToRefreshModeEnable:YES beginHandler:^{

      // to do here when pulling to refresh
}];
```

Dismiss pull to refresh tableview

```
    import <HTTableKit/TableKit>

....

[tableview  dismissPullToRefreshEndHandler:^{

      // to do here when dismissing     
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's our tutorial on Custom Pull-to-Refresh controls, with code for Objective-C and Swift: http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

To add additional text or images, as you mentioned, add them into `self.refreshLoadingView` in the `setupRefreshControl` or `scrollViewDidScroll` methods (from the tutorial).

Let me know if that helps!