# How to edit or add a UIView underneath a UITableView bounce area (top) ? Like Twitter's - Updating etc

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview

The main Twitter app uses a UITableView for all your tweets and when you drag the UITableView from down from the top it exposes the bounce area underneath which has a UIView that says "Updating..." etc.

How does one access this area underneath to customize it, and how does one detect where the TOP bounce area has been exposed?

I know there is the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` delegate method which I have already implemented. This method basically *always* fires off if the user drags and scrolls into the top bounce or bottom bounce areas since the table needs *bounce* back into position. I don't see how one can detect whether they hit the top or bottom area?

I suppose you could check content offset at start of drag and compare with the offset at end of drag?

How do you actually EDIT or add a subview to the bounce areas though like Twitter / Facebook Feeds? I thought it would be by just adding a UIView subview **underneath** the UITableView, which would then expose it when the TableView is dragged too far but this didn't work?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133567/pull-to-refresh-ios)   You should be able to follow how it works.