# How to animate scroll a view like "pull to refresh"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

My app is showing the following:

[image: Sample 1]

'Sample 1' is just a view to display content. After I click up button, 'Sample 1' will scroll up and a new view 'Sample 2' will be showed from bottom, the final result is :

[image: Sample 2]

I think I should append the sample 2 view at the end of up button, and just adjust the frame of sample 1 and up button to show sample 2.

But I don't know the details how to implement it. Is there a easy way to implement this?

Comment: What has this to do with 'pull to refresh' ?

Comment: If any of the provided solutions have aided in solving this problem, please either mark a solution that has answered the problem and/or up-vote any answers that you have found to be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your button and the 2 sample view's in the UIScrollview and set the contentsize of the scrollview to the total height of the button and the 2 sample view's.

Next, you could disable the scrolling on the UIScrollView and connect the button to a method scrolling the UIScrollView up.

Assuming you got your UIScrollView and the 'sample' view's as properties in your custom UIViewController class you could do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //disable scrolling
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

//connect this action to you button
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    //if current position is top scroll down, otherwise scroll up.
    if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.y < 1){
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.sample1.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [enormego (EGO)](http://developers.enormego.com/). Refer to this question:

[Pull to Refresh (ios)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133567/1548523)

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this using scroll view. Add the views in a scroll view and when the up button is pressed just scroll to the respective position.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before and before I get say anything about it, you want to be careful because you're creating a view larger than the screen size and therefor you are technically rendering a larger than regular view all the time. Avoiding this (while not necessary) may let you unload a view from screen if you can.

That aside, have your main view appear in a UIScrollView so you can adjust the view's position.

The code may look like:

```
- (IBAction)upButtonPress:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        // Approximate frame origin difference
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = self.view.frame.size.height - upButton.frame.size.height;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // if necessary, do something when animation completes
    }];
}
```